# How to improve render performance of component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactJS, I should create a tree component to load data with static data or dynamic data, any way, I want to make it transparent for users, that is to say, user just support the data and the tree component is responsilbe to translate the data to tree node data.

data user support:

```
[{
  id:1,
  name:'Node 1'
},
{
  id:2,
  name:'Node 2'
}]
```

the data tree component translated:

```
[{
  key:1,
  nodeText:'Node 1',
  selected:true
 },
 {
  key:2,
  nodeText:'Node 2',
  selected:false
}]
```

user may change the tree data some time, so I should translate again and again in the render function.

```
class Tree{
  render(){
     // execute the translation between data user supported to node data
     this.translateData();

     // logic to create nodes.
     return '<ul>node element</ul>';
  }
}
```

It is terrible to execute the translation many times. Actually there are some workround to avoid this:
(1) expose the refs and define a reload function and call it by refs.

(2) with the 'shouldComponentUpdate', but there are many tree node data, the selected, the checkable also should re-render the tree, it is complicate to control in this function.

(3) make the tree more simple to just show the tree node data, the translation should be done by the user, not the tree itsself. but I want make the tree rich features to handles this case.

It is precisely because user can support it any time, it become comlicate. If user only support at initialization, it will just process it in constructor or componentDidMount(). but due to the data change, it is difficult to refresh or force reload. I also want reload it with refs, it is unrecommended.

So if anyone encounter this scenarios, please support some advices or solutions?

Comment: "It is terrible to execute the translation many times" --- ... because? Is it really expensive or you assume it is expensive?

Comment: @zerkms, Ok, I thought of, if the data is more than 100,000, or the translation is time-consuming. Acutally, every state changed of parent element, it will execute it again. So I think it is terrible, althought it will not impact on DOM sometiems, but the compulation is not well. So do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You can move the `translateData()` call out of the `render` method and put it into the `componentWillReceiveProps()` lifecycle method. This way, you can also check if the data is changed before translate.

Comment: @Tr1et, great suggestion, but the limitation is that it is efficient when reference change, it there is no other great solutions, I will take this.

Comment: "So do you have any suggestions?" --- I totally have: performance optimisation should be guided by profiling results, not assumptions. Take your real application, profile it, tell if the `this.translateData();` is a bottleneck.

Comment: @zerkms, right, but just because react component assume the shouldComponentUpdate return true by default,this indeed will become the potential fator for performance if possible. In fact, I just think this is not a good design, so want to get a better design for this.

Comment: It is okay to invoke a function if you need to invoke it. It's not okay to optimise something that is not proven to be a problem.